# Error when trying to run XGBoost using Caret

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost

I get this error when I try to run XGBoost using Caret

**Error in train.default(x = x, y = y, trControl = xgb_trcontrol, tuneGrid = xgb_grid,  : 
  At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).**

Here's the structure of the data

```
str(datafinal)
'data.frame':   747467 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ CustSegment : Factor w/ 5 levels "Corporate","Legal",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ SubSegment1 : Factor w/ 23 levels "Academic","Association.foundation.Trust",..: 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 ...
 $ BrandCode   : Factor w/ 2 levels "PPC","QF": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Qty         : int  1 1 1 0 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 ...
 $ Price       : num  0 285 395 415 180 ...
 $ Discount    : num  0 0 20 20 0 0 0 0 0 20 ...
 $ ProductGroup: Factor w/ 228 levels "AAL","AAT","AAU",..: 20 20 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 20 ...
 $ Year        : int  2016 2016 2014 2014 2016 2016 2016 2017 2016 2014 ...
 $ Month       : int  8 8 4 11 4 4 6 1 12 5 ...
 $ Top1Percent : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ estore      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Here's the code

```
# import data
library(caret)
library(readr)
datafinal <- read_csv("~/Document_Repository/estore_Cleaned_Data.csv")

# convert characters to factors and ensure syntactically valid names out of character vectors 

datafinal$CustSegment <- make.names(datafinal$CustSegment)
datafinal$SubSegment1 <- make.names(datafinal$SubSegment1)
datafinal$BrandCode <- make.names(datafinal$BrandCode)
datafinal$ProductGroup <- make.names(datafinal$ProductGroup)
datafinal$Top1Percent <- make.names(datafinal$Top1Percent)

datafinal$CustSegment <- as.factor(datafinal$CustSegment)
datafinal$SubSegment1 <- as.factor(datafinal$SubSegment1)
datafinal$BrandCode <- as.factor(datafinal$BrandCode)
datafinal$ProductGroup <- as.factor(datafinal$ProductGroup)
datafinal$Top1Percent <- as.factor(datafinal$Top1Percent)


colnames(datafinal) <- make.names(colnames(datafinal))

# run xgboost analysis
library(xgboost)

set.seed(123)
train= sample(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE), nrow(datafinal),rep=TRUE)
test = (!train)
datafinal.train <- datafinal[train,]
datafinal.test <- datafinal[test,]

# set up cross validated hyper parameter search

xgb_grid <- expand.grid(
    nrounds = 100,
    eta = c(0.3,0.1,0.01),
    max_depth = c(1,2,4,8),
    gamma = c(0,1)
)

xgb_trcontrol <- trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 5,
    verboseIter = T,
    returnData = F,
    returnResamp = "all",
    classProbs = T,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
    allowParallel = T)

# train the model   
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

x = as.matrix(datafinal.train %>% 
                        select (-estore))

y = as.factor(datafinal.train$estore)                       

xgb_train <- train(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
    tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
    method = "xgbTree"
)

Error in train.default(x = x, y = y, trControl = xgb_trcontrol, tuneGrid = xgb_grid,  : 
  At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
```

I understand that ProductGroup has 228 levels, therefore I tried to onehotcode that column using the following code, and used make.names() on the resulting columns. But had no luck and same error.

```
simpleMod <- dummyVars(~ProductGroup, data = datafinal, levelsOnly = T)
ProductGroup <- as.data.frame(predict(simpleMod, datafinal))

datafinal <- cbind(datafinal,ProductGroup)
datafinal$ProductGroup <- NULL
```

I even tried to One hot encode all columns, and still no champagne.

Here's the new data structure

```
str(datafinal, list.len = 270)
'data.frame':   747467 obs. of  264 variables:
 $ BrandCode                   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Qty                         : int  1 1 1 0 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 ...
 $ Price                       : num  0 285 395 415 180 ...
 $ Discount                    : num  0 0 20 20 0 0 0 0 0 20 ...
 $ Year                        : int  2016 2016 2014 2014 2016 2016 2016 2017 2016 2014 ...
 $ Month                       : int  8 8 4 11 4 4 6 1 12 5 ...
 $ Top1Percent                 : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ estore                      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AAL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AAT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AAU                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AET                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AFI                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AFT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AIT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ALG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ANN                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ARE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ASB                         : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ BCL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BKR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BSL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BTB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BTT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BVC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BVT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CAB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CAR                         : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ CAS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CAT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CBL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CCT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CD_                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CON                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CRB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CRT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DBP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DBT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DEP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DIV                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DLR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DON                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ EBP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ EGA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ EGT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ELG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ELT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FAP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FAS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FSP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FTE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GAP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GAR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GAS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GCB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GCR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GEP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GFS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GFT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GOT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GOV                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GPM                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GQC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GRA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GRO                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GSA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GUN                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HCR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HLC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HOA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HTL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HUD                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ICC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ICF                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IDT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IFA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IPL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IPT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IRS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ITG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LLC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LSA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LSS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ML2                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MLC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NBK                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NFS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NOT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPH                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPO                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NPT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NTE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NUN                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NWT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OFS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PBS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PCA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PCR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PFO                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PFP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PFS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PHY                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PLG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PLS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PNP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PRC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PRF                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PRL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PSS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PTU                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PUB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PUT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q13                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q14                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q15                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q16                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q17                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q40                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Q4R                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QAS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QBP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QCA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QDE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QFT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QHC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QIP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QIR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QLB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QLI                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QPE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QSB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QSM                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QSS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ QST                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RET                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RFS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RPV                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RST                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SBC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SPD                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SPR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SPT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ T20                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ T2S                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ T41                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ T55                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ T65                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TAB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TBX                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TCB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TCH                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TDB                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TFT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TID                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TIN                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TPS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TRE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TSC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TXC                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TXL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VAL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W10                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W11                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W12                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W13                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W14                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W15                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W16                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W17                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W18                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W19                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W20                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W21                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W22                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W23                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W24                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W25                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W26                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W27                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W28                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W29                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W30                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W31                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W32                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W33                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W34                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W35                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W36                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W39                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W41                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W49                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W4M                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W50                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W52                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W70                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W72                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W73                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W74                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W75                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W77                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W78                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W81                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W84                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W86                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W87                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W88                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W91                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W92                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ W97                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WCA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WHW                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WML                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WNA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WNR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WSP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WUS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X706                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X990                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XBS                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XCA                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XCE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XCG                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XCP                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XCR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XDT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XFL                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XIR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XLI                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XSE                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XTR                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XTT                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ XTX                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Academic                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Association.foundation.Trust: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Church                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Federal..Government         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Local.Government            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Miscellaneous               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Non.Profit.Organization     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Other                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Reserved                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Revenue..1B                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Revenue..500M..749          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Revenue..750M.999M          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Revenue.less.than..500M     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ State.Government            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Unknown                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X0.20.Attorneys             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X0.3.employee               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X16.30.employees            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X21.79.Attorneys            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X31..employees              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X4.7.employees              : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X8.15.employees             : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X80..Attorneys              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Corporate                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Legal                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Other CustSegment           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Professional                : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PublicSector                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: I thought, but am no expert, that xgboost requires all numeric data. Confirmed perhaps by this https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/xgboost-algorithm-easy-steps/ which recommends one hot encoding of all categorical variables

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).